# Akka Typed testing - Expect message of type without knowing message details

Tags: scala, akka, akka-testkit, akka-typed

Let's say I have an Actor (OrderGenerator) that in response to an incoming message (GenerateOrder), sends a message to another Actor (OrderProcessor) of type Order.

```
case class Order(orderId: String, partNumber: String, orderQty: Int) // ...etc.
```

In OrderGenerator's receiveMessage() method for the GenerateOrder message, we create an Order object.  The orderId value is generated at this time (let's say it's a UUID generated on the fly).  It then sends this Order as a message to the OrderProcessor Actor.

```
  Behaviors.receiveMessage {
    case GenerateOrder(partNumber: String, orderQty: Int) =>
      val newOrder = Order(orderId=GenerateUUID(), partNumber=partNumber, orderQty=orderQty)
      orderProcessor ! newOrder
      Behaviors.same
```

Ok, now I want to test this.

```
val inbox = TestInbox[Order]()
val TestKit = BehaviorTestKit(OrderGenerator(orderProcessor=inbox.ref))
testKit.run(GenerateOrder(partNo="widgetX", orderQty=5))
inbox.expectMessage(Order( ??????? ))
```

As you can see, I don't know what the full details are of the expected Order, since the orderId is generated by OrderGenerator at runtime, and I can't predict what the UUID will be.

How can I test that an Order message is sent, without knowing what the details will be (or only some of them)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this might sound kind of an "unsafe approach" (I don't think there's any other choice though), but just took a look at [docs of akka TestInbox](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/actor/testkit/typed/scaladsl/TestInbox.html), you can use these 2 methods and use other fields of your order as assertions:

```
assert(inbox.hasMessages())
val message = inbox.receiveMessage()
assert(message.isInstanceOf[Order]) // or essentially any other comparison, like message.partNo == "widgetX"
```